# Trying to convert an extended Array.prototype to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

I got a random image rotator working by using the following script ([demo](http://painfulmouth.com/index4.php)). But I was told that it is a bad practice to extend `Array.prototype`. And it does. It conflicts with the chained select box unless I modify the selected box script. So I guess it's better to not use `Array.prototype.shuffle` ,isn't it?

Here's The script:

```
                Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
                var s = [];
                while (this.length) s.push(this.splice(Math.random() * this.length, 1));
                while (s.length) this.push(s.pop());
                return this;
            }

            var picData = [
                ['img1','url_1'],
                ['img2','url_2'],
                ['img3','url_3'],

            picO = new Array();
            randIndex = new Array(); 
            for(i=0; i < picData.length; i++){
                picO[i] = new Image();
                picO[i].src = picData[i][0];
                picO[i].alt = picData[i][1];
                randIndex.push(i);
            }
            randIndex.shuffle();
            window.onload=function(){
                var mainImgs = document.getElementById('carouselh').getElementsByTagName('img');


                for(i=0; i < mainImgs.length; i++){
                    mainImgs[i].src = picO[randIndex[i]].src;
                    mainImgs[i].parentNode.href = picData[randIndex[i]][1];
                    mainImgs[i].alt = picData[randIndex[i]][1];
                }

            }
```

I'm not sure where to start. I'm reading this [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/), should I do something like

```
    Array.shuffle = function() {for(var 
a=[];this.length;)a.push(array.splice(Math.random()*array.length,1));
for(;a.length;)this.push(a.pop());return this};
```

Would anyone please point me in some directions to rewrite that part?

Comment: Don't forget to declare your variables, `i` is global. Also literal syntax is always preferred, so `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to use a known shuffle algorithm for this.

This stackoverflow answer describes the Fisher-Yates shuffle and provides a function for you to use.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/423413

Bottom line use that function and replace your `Array.prototype.shuffle` function and call it something like `shuffleArray`

```
var shuffleArray = function(arr) {
    ...
}
```

Then replace the line that says `randIndex.shuffle()` with a call to the new function.

```
shuffleArray(randIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- As *elclanrs* mentions, `randIndex = [];` is preferred over `randIndex = new Array();`
- Also as *elclanrs* mentions, you have global variables: `i`, `picO`, and `randIndex`.
- If you like to `randIndex.shuffle();`, then you could add the `shuffle` to `randIndex` straight. This is only a good idea if you will only ever shuffle `randIndex` which seems to be the case. So then you can do this:

  ```
  randIndex.shuffle = function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = this.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (currentIndex) {
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = this[currentIndex];
      this[currentIndex] = this[randomIndex];
      this[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
  }
  ```
- This: `picO[i] = new Image();` does not seem to make sense, since you are not using the generated image anywhere. You might as well use `picO[i] = {}`;
- It does not make sense to randomize an array with indexes, you might as well randomize `picO` and not use `randIndex` at all
- In fact, it does not make sense to have an array of arrays which you then convert to an array of objects with the same data points, why not have the array of objects from the start ?
- `mainImgs[i].alt = picData[randIndex[i]][1];` should at least be

  ```
  `mainImgs[i].alt = picO[randIndex[i]].alt;`
  ```
- All in all, your code could be written as:

  ```
  var picData = [
    {src: 'img1', url: 'url_1'},
    {src: 'img2', url: 'url_2'},
    {src: 'img3', url: 'url_3'},
  ];
  //Perfect shuffling routine, I must say yours is shorter and might suffice
  picData.shuffle  = function shuffle() {
    var currentIndex = this.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (currentIndex) {
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;
      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = this[currentIndex];
      this[currentIndex] = this[randomIndex];
      this[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
      }
  };

  picData.shuffle();

  window.onload=function(){
    var mainImgs = document.getElementById('carouselh').getElementsByTagName('img');

    for(var i=0; i < mainImgs.length; i++){
      mainImgs[i].src             = picData[i].src;
      mainImgs[i].parentNode.href = picData[i].url;
      mainImgs[i].alt             = picData[i].url;
    }
  };
  ```

The only problem I still see is stuffin `window.onload` instead of using an [EventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902033/element-onload-vs-element-addeventlistenerload-callbak-false), I will leave that up to you.